# Subversion connection failed using Tortoise SVN but working with IE

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am unable to connect to our Subversion URL using Tortoise SVN but I am able to connect the same URL using Internet Explorer.

In my Internet Explorer I have configured the proxy settings, same applied to Tortoise SVN Network settings.

Please help to me resolve this issue.

Comment: What error do you get in TortoiseSVN?

Comment: TortoiseSVN comes with the Subversion command line client. Have you tried that? Whenever you have problems with Tortoise, you should always try the command line client. Take a look at [this post] which will tell you how to configure the command line client's proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Be good to get a Wireshark / network capture of the requests for the working and non-working requests.

Are you using the http protocol?

What does the server URL look like?

Typically browsers can handle HTTP redirects but other svn clients (like Tortoise) cannot.